# Any examples of a Log4net Rolling Daily file appender sent via email?

Tags: logging, log4net, logfile, email-notifications, fileappender

This is done inside of a mvc5 application, setting up the file appenders was the easy part.  Now I'm stuck as to how to go about setting up a logging such that:

1. Daily file logging names are in the format "logfileName-{month}-{day}-{year}.txt" format
2. Setting up a daily log file appender such that after 24 hours the log file or log information is sent to a email address.

I'm surprised that I'm having such a hard time finding examples of such a solution.  I don't think what I'm doing is revolutionary or unique.  Any examples or documentation (especially for the email smtp part) would be greatly appreciated.

And yes I have looked at http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Comment: For item 1, set the `datePattern` attribute appropriately, and regarding item 2 see. [Sending errors in a roll up digest email with log4net](http://andrewchaa.me.uk/2013/01/07/sending-errors-in-a-roll-up-digest-email-with-log4net/)

Answer (score 0):

For 1, set DatePattern with extension in quotes

```
<param name="DatePattern" value="MM-dd-yyyy'.txt'"/>
```